# Only create list in python with every 5th item?

Tags: python, list, indices

I have a list of 20 items. I want to create a new list than only contains every 5th item of the list.

Here is was I have:

```
    listA=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    for i in len(range(listA)):
      print i
```

How can I create `listB` from `listA` using Python? `listB` should be equal to `[5, 10, 15, 20]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this idiom

```
listB = listA[4::5]
```

This means starting from index `4`, pick every 5th element.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is using the `range()` function to create a list of integers with increments (steps) of 5 between them, then using them to access the indexes of the original list to append them to a new one:

```
listB=[]
for i in range(4,len(listA),5):
    listB.append(listA[i])
```

The `range(start, stop[, step])` function returns a list of integers, based on the arguments used:

1. `start` - the first integer in the list (optional, defaults to `0`).
2. `stop` - the last integer generated in the list will be the greatest, but less than the value of `stop` (`stop` will not be in the list).
3. `step` - the increment for values in the list (defaults to `1`, can be made negative - to produce decreasing lists).